# How to code for the "split screen view" in ie10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, windows-8, internet-explorer-10

My webapp auto-adjusts to the width of the browser window but in the "metro" or "modern" ie10 when you put the window in split mode (20/80) where IE is only 20% of the screen it zooms out the content.

I have a specific mobile view that I use for small width screens and which would be ideal for this sidebar view. Is there any way I can keep that window from zooming out the content and creating a "fake width"?

I hope I have been clear enough. if not please tell me.

thanks for your suggestions and help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the following to the media-query you're using for snapped view:

```
@-ms-viewport { width: 320px; }
```

Take a look at [Adapting Your Site to Different Window Sizes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/06/19/adapting-your-site-to-different-window-sizes.aspx) for more context.